# Google Places Picker IOS customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the Google Place Picker APi and wanted to know if there is a way to remove the back button and the search button and also prevent the map from moving around, that is created with the `_placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];` ?

if not, is there an alternative i can use that provides same functionality? Basically, I want the the closest points of interest near a users location..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to figure that out.  So far, what I've come up with is to combine GMSMapView and GMSPlacesClient into your own custom viewcontroller.

To gather the nearby points of interest, you'll use the GMSPlacesClient:

```
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()
    likelyPlace = [GMSPlaces]()

    placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoods, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error with Current place: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods{
                    for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {

                        let place = likelihood.place
                        self.likelyPlaces.append(place)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

this will put the nearby places in your likelyPlaces array.  Then it's up to you how you'd want to display the contents.  Maybe put them in a tableView or as annotations on the map.

Hope this helps.